# open websocket connection firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, websocket

Is it possible for a firefox addon to establish a websocket connections?

When I try:

```js
var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
var ws = gBrowser.contentWindow.window.WebSocket ||
         gBrowser.contentWindow.window.MozWebSocket;    
var websocket = new ws(wsUri);
```

In the Error Console the message says

> Error: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://echo.websocket.org/.

Comment: Have you tried the examples from there :
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)

Comment: I've moved a lot further. it's just that from the FF addon javascript the socket doesn't want to connenct anymore

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Firefox 14, no error messages. Note that `gBrowser.contentWindow.WebSocket` is sufficient to access the constructor (actually, you could also use the `WebSocket` constructor in your own window, no need to go inside the browser for that).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it seems the only option is to proxy your WebSocket messages through a `PageWorker`. There is an example of how to do this on this website:

http://austinhartzheim.me/blog/4/websockets-firefox-sdk-addons/

Comment: This is awesome, I'm going to look at it, do you have any other examples by any chance? That demo in that website gives me `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8888/.`